# optimizing display of a 5MB query result using python and VueJS

Tags: python, mysql, vue.js

I have a web application using python on the server (bottle) and VueJS in the client.
one frontend component display's a paginated result of a query which ends in more then 10k records. the records are saved as python `dict` and sent to the frontend. the size of the result is 5.5MB approximately which with my internet connection ends with more then 2 seconds of waiting.

the api path to handle the request looks like this:

```
@cmCampaigns.get('/api/campaignManager/campaigns')
@authorize()
def get():
    resp = {}
    usr = authlayer.current_user
    user_id = dao.App().getUserID(usr.username)
    resp["campaigns"] = CampaignsData().get_revcontent_campaigns(user_id)

    return resp
```

and the query itself looks like this:

```
def get_campaigns(self, user_id):
    query = "SELECT rc.account_id, rc.campaign_id, " \
            "rc.campaign_name, rc.start_date, rc.end_date, " \
            "rc.enabled, rc.default_bid, " \
            "rc.budget, rc.cost, ctr,rc.country_codes, " \
            "'revcontent' AS provider, " \
            "replace(JSON_EXTRACT(ac.account_json,'$.client_id'),'\"','') AS account_name, " \
            "CASE enabled " \
            "WHEN enabled = 'active' THEN 'on' " \
            "WHEN enabled = 'inactive' THEN 'off' " \
            "END AS enabled_val " \
            "FROM prv_campaigns AS rc " \
            "INNER JOIN websites AS ws " \
            "ON rc.website_id = ws.website_id " \
            "INNER JOIN website_users AS wu " \
            "ON wu.website_id = ws.website_id " \
            "INNER JOIN prv_accounts ac " \
            "ON rc.account_id = ac.account_id " \
            "WHERE wu.user_id = %s " \
            "ORDER BY id DESC"
    try:
        data = self.db.query(query, user_id)
        return data
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e.message)
        return -1, e.message
```

i tried to optimize the query as possible, but it is still not enogh. 
What "best practice" solution's are there to optimize this common logic? compressing the dict before sending it? i wa thinking about pagination but then my filtering and sorting logic is in the client and so lots of data is obviously gone.....any recommendations?? thx

Comment: If your frontend is paginated, could you limit the size of one query to the content of one page?

Comment: i could, but then if user search for some data it will be limited to the data i present in the current page, which is obviously problematic

Comment: You could make the search run server side as well. I think with the size of your dataset you will need to hit the server for each page, either with or without a search query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pagination you can use LIMIT & OFFSET

Optimization ? run "EXPLAIN" before the query and bring the output

Lets take a quick look

```
SELECT rc.account_id, 
       rc.campaign_id, 
       rc.campaign_name, 
       rc.start_date, 
       rc.end_date, 
       rc.enabled, 
       rc.default_bid, 
       rc.budget, 
       rc.cost, 
       ctr, 
       rc.country_codes, 
       'revcontent'                                                   AS 
       provider, 
       Replace(Json_extract(ac.account_json, '$.client_id'), '"', '') AS 
       account_name, 
       CASE enabled 
         WHEN enabled = 'active' THEN 'on' 
         WHEN enabled = 'inactive' THEN 'off' 
       END                                                            AS 
       enabled_val 
FROM   prv_campaigns AS rc 
       inner join websites AS ws 
               ON rc.website_id = ws.website_id 
       inner join website_users AS wu 
               ON wu.website_id = ws.website_id 
       inner join prv_accounts ac 
               ON rc.account_id = ac.account_id 
WHERE  wu.user_id = %s 
ORDER  BY id DESC
```

- enabled column should be numeric or enum, it will save strcmp time
- Replace(Json_extract(ac.account_json, '$.client_id'), '"', '') ? extract all account name do your thing in client side
- 2 inner joins ? might be a design issue

Comment: so please bring "EXPLAIN" output and edit or click on ^